# How to keep restarting a Windows cmd prompt

Tags: bash, cmd, cygwin, bash-trap

Cygwin's bash is often preferable to Windows' cmd command shell, so we use it to set up our environments before spawning a Windows shell.  However, halting execution of a running process in this spawned shell with **Ctrl-C** kills boots the user back to the bash shell.

My attempted workaround:

```
source setupEnvironment.sh

restartCommand() {
  # Reset trap
  trap restartCommand SIGINT
  echo -e " === Restarting windows cmd prompt\n"
  cmd /k 
}

trap restartCommand SIGINT
echo -e " === Starting windows cmd prompt\n"
cmd /k
```

This approach only restarts cmd once. Subsequent Ctrl-C's are not caught. Is there a way to keep restarting the cmd process?

Comment: Curious why you can't do everything in bash itself, why do you need to start cmd at all?

Comment: @Miserable Variable: personally, I'm happy staying in bash. But others at work want the cmd prompt. So I compromised: I'll invoke cmd, but only after setting up the environment in bash (bash does everything better!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it have to be in the same window? If not, I have had much better luck with

```
cygstart cmd
```

`cmd` starts in its own window; and only exit closes that window

Comment: Nice workaround. The extra window isn't ideal, but everything then works as expected.

Comment: The cygstart options `--wait` might be useful here.

Comment: I tried that - but the process stays on in the background without the user knowing. Just an extra process and a couple MB of RAM, but when you rarely restart your PC, that could add up.

Comment: Which process? Bash? How is `bash` started? Another alternative is for the bash process to exit after starting cmd using cygstart (without --wait). BTW even when you start cmd without cygstart the bash process stays in memory

Comment: Whoops, my last comment referred to `--hide`.  This closed the window but the parent **process** stayed active. Trying `--wait` didn't seem to do anything useful either. Yes, the best solution for now is `cygstart cmd /K; exit`. What I didn't say was this bash prompt was actually started from a cmd prompt - so the bash prompt is effectively sandwiched between 2 cmd prompts, unknown to the user. So exiting bash doesn't exit the original cmd prompt.

Comment: Oh hmmm. Given this scenario I think it is best if you set the environment in cmd itself :) Or perhaps create a .bat file using bash (change `export x=y` to `echo set x=y >> envvars.bat` and execute the generated bat file from cmd, where a called bat file can modify the caller's env

Comment: Haha - yeah, that's where I started, with 2 parallel scripts to setup a development environment (on Linux and Windows). There is significant overlap, so I combined them to reduce maintenance. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Subsequent Ctrl-Cs aren't caught because your script exits due to reaching the end.

Chances are cmd will return error when you ctrl-c, in which case you could do

```
until cmd /k; do true; done
```

Otherwise, make your script loop, until ctrl-c isn't pressed:

```
trap restart=1 SIGINT
echo -e " === Starting windows cmd prompt\n"
restart=1
while (( restart )); do restart=0; cmd /k; done
```

Comment: Thanks - both answers works reasonably well, and may be the best I can hope for. When cmd is in the middle of compiling, Ctrl-C still frequently boots back to bash though. Also, the cmd window sometimes locks up and may be closed only by End Process from Task Manager.

Answer (score 1):

To *complement* [Miserable Variable's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14615275/45375) with an explanation of **why opening `cmd.exe` in its *own* console window is the best approach**:

- While you can try to work around the <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> issue as demonstrated in [that other guy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14614204/45375), the behavior is not quite the same as in a regular `cmd.exe` console window: since a *new instance* of `cmd.exe` is created every time <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> is pressed, previous state is lost.
- The Cygwin terminal (console window) uses the UTF-8 character encoding rather than the regular console window's encoding that is based on the (legacy) OEM code page, and the two are incompatible.
- Curiously, staying in the Cygwin terminal causes `cmd.exe` to *echo* all interactively submitted commands (as you'd get in a batch file without `@echo off`).

To automatically close the Cygwin window when launching the `cmd.exe` console window, use
`exec cygstart cmd`.